# Lock mysql table to prevent select and insert at the same time

Tags: mysql, innodb, select, insert

I know this question has been asked earlier and I have also read the documentation. But I guess I'm stupid not understand.

I have a code that inserts a row and the row should be unique in several field values. But to make this new data really live delivered to the visitors it updates (if new data, inserting it) via ajax and every 5th second. This means it sometimes insert two or more rows at the same time.

I have a `SELECT` query before the `INSERT` to check if the row (a row with the exactly same data) already exist. And I also use `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.
Yet duplicate rows appearing.

I'm using innoDB.

I have googled and found `LOCK` functions but not figured out how to use it. And does it even work for `SELECT`? The best would be to LOCK the `SELECT` query checking if the row already exist.

Answer (score 2):

With `LOCK` you probably mean locking entire table, that should not be needed in InnoDB. Check [SELECT .. FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

But duplicate values should be forbidden with the use of `UNIQUE` indexes, that way the worst thing you get is an "duplicate key" error and not a duplicated row.

If you have proper indexes in place, you may even use [INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Yes I want to lock the entire table. And yes I have read that it shouldn't be needed in innoDB then using transations. But somehow it doesn't work. Maybe this locking doesn't affect reading (`SELECT`)? The `UNIQUE` index should and will be used from now on. But, unfortunately, there are several tables affected in this process, stats being updated with +1 and so on. So the best would be to make this `SELECT` with it's `if`-statement checking for the whole process to begin to be locked.

Comment: You need to issue a [WRITE lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html) on the table(s) to forbid reading from other threads. Using `FOR UPDATE` "blocks" only other selects which are `FOR UPDATE` too (and inserts/updates/deletes). It does not block "normal" read-only selects in the default isolation. It has to be INSIDE a started transaction (otherwise the lock is released in the moment the select finishes) and it does lock only some rows, not entire table (but that is enough to assure consistent data).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this in your session

```
SET autocommit = 0;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
START TRANSACTION
SELECT ...
INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

`SERIALIZABLE` causes `SELECTs` to do the locking for you

Here is what the [MySQL Documentation says on `SERIALIZABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

> This level is like REPEATABLE READ, but InnoDB implicitly converts all plain SELECT statements to SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE if autocommitis disabled. If autocommit is enabled, the SELECT is its own transaction. It therefore is known to be read only and can be serialized if performed as a consistent (nonlocking) read and need not block for other transactions. (To force a plain SELECT to block if other transactions have modified the selected rows, disable autocommit.)

If you close your session, the next session you open will have autocommit back at 1. That means you will have to disable autocommit and set `SERIALIZABLE` each time.

Perhaps `READ COMMITTED` would be better

```
SET autocommit = 0;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION
SELECT ...
INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

Documentation Says

> READ COMMITTED
>
> A somewhat Oracle-like isolation level with respect to consistent (nonlocking) reads: Each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot. See Section 14.2.2.2, “Consistent Nonlocking Reads”.
>
> For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE), UPDATE statements, and DELETE statements, InnoDB locks only index records, not the gaps before them, and thus permits the free insertion of new records next to locked records.

At any rate, try a different transaction isolation level.

**NOTE: Try it on a Staging Server first.**

Answer (score 1):

If the table is declared with

```
UNIQUE(x,y,z)
```

Then you are totally protected and you don't need to do anything.  No Locks.  You will never get two rows with the same combination if x,y,z.